# Is there a way to make a BLE tag secure without too much effort in programming it?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hardware-interface, hardware

Does anybody know if there is a commercial BLE tag that cannot be copied and can communicate with a BLE HM-10 module.

So, programming it before, I can "install" on it a private key that can be read out by a Master BLE device and I can be sure there is nobody in the middle of communication or my tag has not been "copied".

For clarity, I explain the project: a BLE tag OR a mobile device (Android or iOS) should communicate, like a strong key and high security, with a HM-10 master.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the Bluetooth standard for this. You can of course implement some public key cryptography yourself, but that has nothing to do with BLE then. You probably want a certificate in all devices, signed by a "CA" (your company). Clients should then verify the authenticity using the public key of the CA. This is exactly what TLS does.

I'm not sure however if HM-10 restricts what you can do or not.

Comment: This means that I have to program each peripherical device with a different certificate? There is no way to avoid this operation, even with RFID technology?

Comment: Using certificates is the common way to ensure genuineness. To copy it someone needs the private key, which should be very hard to extract. Secure RFID tags follow that idea too.